# setting PYTHON_LIBRARY during opencv-2.4.10 build

Tags: python, opencv, centos

I'm on CentOS6.7 and I'm building opencv-2.4.10 (I removed 2.4.9 because my python cv2 package didn't seem to go along with underneath opencv-2.4.9.  When I print cv2.__version__ in python, it shows 2.4.10 so I figured I should upgrade opencv to 2.4.10 because python cv2 is just a python wrapper for real c++ opencv. Anyways..)

The only environment variable related to python is PYTHON_PATH.

```
ckim@stph45:~/Downloads/opencv-2.4.10/build] echo $PYTHON_PATH
/home/ckim/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/
```

Under /home/ckim/Downloads/opencv-2.4.10/build directory, I did

```
cmake -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON -D
CUDA_GENERATION=Auto ..
```

and I can see the result configuration message some of which related to python seems odd to me. See below.

```
....
--   Python:
--     Interpreter:                 /home/ckim/anaconda2/bin/python2 (ver 2.7.12)
--     Libraries:                   /usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.so
--     numpy:                       /home/ckim/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include (ver 1.10.2)
--     packages path:               lib/python2.7/site-packages
....
```

the Interpreter and numpy is correctly pointing to my anaconda2 python environment, but why is the Library pointing the python installed in my system(not anaconda2)?

I tried passing python related variables in the cmake command as directed [here](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/d9f/tutorial_linux_install.html#gsc.tab=0) but it didn't help. Installing something on CentOS is not a breeze almost always, but I'm sticking on CentOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I succeeded in building opencv-2.4.10 by following commands.

make clean ; cmake -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON -D CUDA_GENERATION=Auto -D PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR=/home/ckim/anaconda2/include/python2.7/ PYTHON_LIBRARY=/home/ckim/anaconda2/lib/libpython2.7.so .. | & tee log.cmake
make -j8 | & tee log.make

now opencv-2.4.10 is installed and cv2 is also 2.4.10.
When I look into log.cmake, I still see

```
Libraries:                   /usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.so (ver 2.7.12)
```

But anyway the compile was a success, so it seems I can ignore this configuration message and the parameter I set in the command line (PYTHON_LIBRARY) only matters.